# Bind to ListBox

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm binding a list to a ListBox, but the data does not show up.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listCities">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CityName}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

and C# code goes as:

```
var q = from h in xmlDoc.Descendants("City")
                select new
                {
                    CityName = h.Element("Name")
                };

        listCities.ItemsSource = q;
```

Any help there. Thanks

Comment: Is `q` containing values when you debug?

Comment: maybe, q.ToList() helps?

Comment: q does contain values. Also q.ToList() did not help

Answer (score 0):

Set the DataContext of the Page to your Viewmodel or this.

```
DataContext = this;
```

Make sure your List<> is an ObservableCollection<>

Comment: I appologize. That was by mistake

Comment: This is only half the answer, as you're not showing the binding of the ListBox, the ObservableCollection property, etc